# JS validation submit does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Why submit handler does not work for 2+ entered signs ('ab', etc.)? 
Error stub runs, but no OK result.
http://jsfiddle.net/v1ojjnnk/

```
<form id="userForm">
    <div id="login">
        login
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="text" id="loginField" name="name">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <button id="register" type="submit">go</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
var $loginField = $('#loginField');
$('#userForm').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       alert('error stub');
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
       alert('good stub');
    },
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        alert('OK stub');
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `errorPlacement` is not the form error handler - that property is used to set where the error label should be displayed.

Comment: @Rory-McCrossan, thank you!